# First time using mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I've been using playing around with jUnit previously. Now I want to use Mockito for learning purposes.

I have a REST WS that looks like this:

```
@Path("postservice")
public class PostWebService {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PostWebService.class);

//Inject of the stateless post session bean for persisting purposes
@EJB
private PostServiceInterface postService;

/*Webservice for persisting of posts*/
@POST
@Path("postmessage")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String insertPost(
        @FormParam("post") String post,
        @Context HttpServletRequest request
) {
    logger.info("insertPost called");
    try {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
    logger.info("Got user from session.");
    if (user != null) {
        postService.insertPost(post, user);
        return "true";
    } else {
        return "false";
    }
}
```

}

This following test case is probably wrong:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PostWebServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
PostWebService pws;
@Mock
PostServiceInterface mockedPostService;
@Mock
HttpServletRequest request;
@Mock
User user;
@Mock
HttpSession session;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    Logger mockedLogger = mock(Logger.class);
}

@Test
public void testInsertPost() throws Exception {
    PostWebService pws = mock(PostWebService.class);
    String post = "Some post";
    when(pws.insertPost(post, request)).thenReturn("true");
    assertTrue(pws.insertPost(post, request) == "true");
}
}
```

I've gotten several errors and I decided to "remove" or make that specific part to pass to see what other errors I have:

First error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at se.chas.fakebook.webservices.PostWebService.insertPost(PostWebService.java:41)
at se.chas.fakebook.webservices.PostWebServiceTest.testInsertPost(PostWebServiceTest.java:42)
```

Line 41 is: User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
Line 42 is: when(pws.insertPost(post, request)).thenReturn("true");

I initliazed the user object to null to see what happens and I got this error this time:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
'setCharacterEncoding' is a *void method* and it *cannot* be stubbed with a *return value*!
 Voids are usually stubbed with Throwables:
doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
```

Then i removed the setCharacterEncoding method and the test passed. Why did it not pass before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this setup, Mockito will create a plain Java object for `PostWebService` and in then wire all the other mocks into it.

That means

```
when(pws.insertPost(post, request)).thenReturn("true");
```

will actually try to execute `insertPost()` since `pws` itself isn't a mock. `when()` can only be used safely for fields annotated with `@Mock`. A good example is this line:

```
User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
```

the test will fail here with an NPE since you `request` is a mock and you didn't tell Mockito what to return for `getSession()`. Use this setup code instead:

```
when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(session);
when(session.getAttribute("user")).thenReturn(user);

assertEquals("true", pws.insertPost(post, request));
```